# websocket connection invalid - Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, socket.io

I developed a web application that uses socket.io on my windows platform, and it worked perfectly. However, as soon as I move it over to my debian 6 production dedicated server, it starts dropping clients for "warn - websocket connection invalid".

This error happens on the server, and drops normally 10-20 seconds after the first connection is established.

socket.io is running at version 0.9.11 on both linux + windows servers

Comment: Maybe some more context would be useful. Do you get this message on the server, or on the client? Try creating a small demo.

Comment: Included some more details

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your ports and connection adresses?

Try updating your socket.io!

Comment: Yeah it connects fine to start with, but then produces the error 10-20 seconds after first connection.

Comment: Try updating your socket.io!

Comment: socket.io is running at version 0.9.11 on both linux + windows servers, I have tried running npm update but it will not fetch a later version.

Comment: is your io.connect() empty? if yes then put there adress, port... for example: `var socket = io.connect("46.139.336.63",  {port: 1234, rememberTransport:false, connectTimeout:10000});`

Comment: Currently using the following code `var socket = io.connect("http://domain:8080");` , will try using the json method as specified in the above post - Tried that, still not working